# Laravel Homestead Vagrant not booting up

Tags: laravel, virtual-machine, vagrant

I had my Vagrant box working fine on my mac with Mavericks.  I added a new project to the homestead.yaml file and when I ran vagrant reload I received the following:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:550:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:550:in `new'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:550:in `block in validate'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:545:in `each'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:545:in `validate'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/config/v2/root.rb:68:in `block in validate'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/config/v2/root.rb:64:in `each'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/config/v2/root.rb:64:in `validate'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:15:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:196:in `action_raw'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:173:in `block in action'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:434:in `lock'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `action'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

I didn't touch anything else.  Now I can't get it booted.  Any ideas?

Comment: One of the nice things about Vagrant is if something isn't working the way it should, you `vagrant destroy && vagrant up`.

Comment: You're right @ceejayoz, it is a handy feature however I still get the same error on `vagrant up`

Answer (score 2):

On this closed issue the guy had the same errors you are having:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3961

Looks like he had a wrong statement in his Vagrant file that was making it crash on startup.  Maybe there is a typo or something like that on your yaml file?  Did you modify the main Vagrantfile or maybe even the homestead.rb file at all?  A typo or error on any of those could be causing your problem.

Answer (score 2):

After spending hours on the issue, I just reinitialized homestead.

1. Deleted the existing homestead folder. 
   rm -rf .homestead
2. initialized homestead. 
    homestead init
3. edit the yaml file

   homestead edit
4. boot up homestead

   homestead up

That got it up and running.